# Float divs inside of Absolute div with Relative Parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

I couldn't find any duplicates of this, so here goes...

http://jsfiddle.net/bmyLru9w/

```
<div style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color:#ff0000"></div>
<div id="base" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color:#00ff00">
    <div id="popup">
        <div>
        <div class="in-pop"></div>
        <div class="in-pop"></div>
        <div class="in-pop"></div>
            <div class="in-pop"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>

.in-pop{
    background-color:#ffff00;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
}

#base{
    position:relative;
}

#popup{
    background-color:#0000ff;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
}
```

I have a div (green) that sits at the bottom of my content. I need a popup (for hover) to be place at the top of that green div. The popup is blue in the fiddle. Then inside of that popup, I have an unknown number of divs that are float:left. My problem is that they stack vertically rather than horizontally and I cannot define a width on the blue div because it changes. It seems to happen because of the "relative" of the green div, but then if I don't use that, I can't position the blue div correctly on top of it.

I could use position: fixed and negative top margin, but negative margins are pretty gross. Maybe that's my only option, though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your main problem is that your `#popup` element is inside of your green div. Therefore it's width is stuck at 30px (100% of it's parent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding this:

```
#popup{
    width: 100vw;
}
```

This will make the blue div always be the width of the viewport so that your items can float like you expect.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhjosjkn/)

Another way might be this:

```
#popup{
    display:flex;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4v6jcyy/)

Comment: Both make it look better, but the vw one wont work because I have backgrounds and other styles to add onto the popup which would stretch to the end of the screen, and the flex is only supported for css3 browsers.

Comment: flexbox is supported in all modern browsers including IE10 and up. If you are trying to support IE9 and below then you'll have to look into a javascript solution

Answer (score 1):

Your `#base` has a fixed width of 30px which is forcing anything within it to be at MOST 30px wide.

**Edit**

I like the Solution the zgood gave by using Flexbox. Here's how to setup flex so that it works in the absolute most browsers:

```
display : -webkit-box;   /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
display : -moz-box;      /* OLD - Firefox 19- (doesn't work very well) */
display : -ms-flexbox;   /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
display : -webkit-flex;  /* NEW - Chrome */
display : flex;          /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense. How can I make the child not rely on the base's width?

Comment: This worked great in FF, Chrome, and Safari, but isn't working in IE10+. Seems that IE hates the idea that theres a flexbox inside of an absolutely positioned div. With tweaking, i can also get it to expand all the items, but it also expands the green box.

Comment: I'm using IE edge, and for me it's working fine. However, the width's of the '.in-pop' don't seem to be. It may just take some playing with, or IE may just not like this method.